# Equation of the lines

Tags: vectors

$P=(1,-1,1)$
$Q=(-1,2,1)$
$R=(0,1,3)$
$S=(-1,-1,-1)$
Find equations for the line $L_1$ joining the midpoints of $PQ$ and $RS$, and the line $L_2$ joining the midpoints of $PR$ and $QS$.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you found the midpoints they ask about?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We will only be able to help if you show some initiative on your part. Do let us know what you have tried and where are you stumbling.

Comment: Well, I found the midpoints to be (-1/2, 1, 1/2) and (-1/2, -1/2, -1/2) and applied the http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/lineplane/img1.gif form but it doesn’t sit right with me.

Comment: It seems to me, that since a line in (for example) $\mathbb{R^3}$ is completely determined by two points, and since you have identified the pertinent points, you need an algorithm for deriving the equation of the line, given 2 points on the line.  What is the **background** of the problem?  For example, if this problem is from a book or class, then what theorems or previously solved problems from your book or class do you think might be pertinent here?